# Cancel a user prompt based on user action within my app

Tags: web3js, metamask

I trigger a transaction from within my application. The Metamask user prompt appears, and the user can accept/reject. Is there a way to cancel this prompt based on user action from within my application? i.e: The user clicks on a button on my page, and that directly translates to a rejection of the previously mentioned prompt?